# How to extract values from complex json object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to drill down and extract values (in order to verify them) from a REST service response formatted as shown in the example below:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "A9001001A23D10A943E48481": {
                "id": "A9001001A23D10A943E48481",
                "type": "WIP",
                "status": "ERROR",
                "message": "could not move document",
                "details": [
                    "No document found with document id 'A9001001A23D10A943E48481'"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "A9001001A23D10A945468483": {
                "id": "A9001001A23D10A945468483",
                "type": "WIP",
                "status": "ERROR",
                "message": "could not move document",
                "details": [
                    "No document found with document id 'A9001001A23D10A945468483'"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "error": {}
}
```

I need to compare actual values for id, type, status, message, and details with the expected values. I do know the id # but need to make sure the other values are correct in the response.

I can get the objects in the data[] array (data[0] and data[1]), but have failed completely to get anything below that. I've tried putting the array object into a map like so, but that doesn't get me very far.

```
let myMap = new Map(Object.entries(jsonData.data[0]));
```

Comment: What is the expected result? Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: You have an inconvenient data structure for what you are trying to do because each object in `data` has a nested object with its id as its key. This makes accessing properties a little more difficult. It forces you to do something like `Object.values(jsonData.data[0])[0].message`

Comment: I don't understand your issue in accessing the data like `console.log(jsonData.data[0].A9001001A23D10A943E48481.details[0])`. If your issue are the "random" IDs in the path, do `const data = jsonData.data.flatMap(Object.values);` and work with this Array instead

Answer (score 0):

In general you could use a **loop to iterate** through **the array** and **accessing the
properties** of each object.

```js
const jsonData = {
  "data": [{
      "A9001001A23D10A943E48481": {
        "id": "A9001001A23D10A943E48481",
        "type": "WIP",
        "status": "ERROR",
        "message": "could not move document",
        "details": [
          "No document found with document id 'A9001001A23D10A943E48481'"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "A9001001A23D10A945468483": {
        "id": "A9001001A23D10A945468483",
        "type": "WIP",
        "status": "ERROR",
        "message": "could not move document",
        "details": [
          "No document found with document id 'A9001001A23D10A945468483'"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "error": {}
};

jsonData.data.forEach((element) => {
  const key = Object.keys(element)[0]; // Get the key of the nested object
  const nestedObject = element[key]; // Access the nested object using the key

  console.log('Id:', nestedObject.id);
  console.log('Type:', nestedObject.type);
  console.log('Status:', nestedObject.status);
  console.log('Message:', nestedObject.message);
  console.log('Details:', nestedObject.details);
});
```

Would be great if you could extend your question with what result you are trying to get, like @Unmitigated commented.

Comment: This also worked very well, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code you could try:

```js
let data=Object.values(jsonData.data[0]);
// ^This is where you will be refering to the data [0] is for the first object
// in this case, the first object is "A9001001A23D10A943E48481"
console.log(data[0].id);
// Here we are refering to the first object in the refered object above and calling the id on it
```

Comment: Thanks!  It worked nicely, am a beginner at JavaScript so really appreciate the help.